# Change Buddypress Activity Stream Date format

Tags: buddypress

I want to change the activity stream date format to make it something like facebook date. I mean I need to use "... ago" date format for today's activities and "December 31, 2012 at 10:00AM" like date format for older activities.

How can I do this? Can this be done without modifying Buddypress core files?

Another question, how to remove the link from the activity date?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The two filters you're looking for are ([source](https://buddypress.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/bp-activity/bp-activity-template.php)):

1. `bp_activity_time_since`
2. `bp_activity_permalink`

To modify the date format, you could probably use the `bp_core_time_since_pre` filter to bypass BuddyPress's time_since calculations ([source](http://buddypress.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/bp-core/bp-core-functions.php)).

Alternatively, you could completely override (i.e. replace) the activity meta output with the `bp_insert_activity_meta` filter